# Not able to switch between functions with switch statement

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a function in which I would like to call another function with a `switch` statement. Independently, all functions and their `switch` cases work properly, but if I call a function in a switch, the called function is not getting executed. This is in Node.js.

```js
FieldArr.forEach(function(entry, index) {
  if (!entry)
    return;

  switch (true) {
    case (/color1/.test(entry)):
      console.log("I got color1");
      display.color1 = red;
      break;
    case (/color2/.test(entry)):
      console.log("I got color2");
      display.color2 = blue;
      break;
    case (/color3/.test(entry)):
      console.log("I got color3");
      display.color1 = yellow;
      break;
    case (/shape/.test(entry)):
      console.log("I got shape");
      shape();
      break;
      // tried removing break from this case, still function black is not getting executed.
  }
})
```

This is function black.

```js
function share() {
  switch (true) {
    case (/shape1/.test(entry)):
      console.log("I got shapel");
      display.color1 = round;
      break;
    case (/shape2/.test(entry)):
      console.log("I got shape2");
      display.color2 = Triangle;
      break;
    case (/shape3/.test(entry)):
      console.log("I got shape3");
      display.color1 = Hexagon;
      break;
    case (/Number1/.test(entry)):
      console.log("I got number1");
      number();
      break;
      // tried removing break from this case, still function black is not getting executed.
  }
}
```

There is function number defined same as black. Is this the right way?

Comment: What does "There is function number defined same as black." mean?

Comment: This question really lacks a [mre]. We have no idea what all these variables mean. Demonstrate the problem. Your description isn’t very clear.

Comment: It doesn't look like you're calling black() anywhere. also, your first switch is calling shape(), but the function you've shared is  named share(). Is this intentional?

Answer (score 2):

I think you need to pass entry to your function to make it work, like so:

```
function share(entry) {
  switch (true) {
    case (/shape1/.test(entry)):
      console.log("I got shapel");
      display.color1 = round;
      break;
...
```

Otherwise, how would it know, which entry to work with?